# Check In between two times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to check in IF in sql server..

I am having check in time

and parm1time and paramtime2

I want to return the value if checkin time is between param1 and param2

how can I write.

Example @checkin = 10.00
param1 = 2.00
param2 = 13.00

How can I do this in sql query IF COndition

Comment: Can you please rewrite this question? It's very hard to understand anything

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
....
WHERE @checkin BETWEEN @param1 AND @param2
```

or

```
....
IF @checkin BETWEEN @param1 AND @param2
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

```
IF @checkin >= param1 AND @checkin <= param2 BEGIN
    -- // do stuff
END
```